# Not able to load jar file from .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have made a .bat file and trying to run my java application through it now i have problem with it that it is not able to load Jar as Shown in Image
here is the Code below

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH="
for /R ./lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
  set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
)
set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!"
echo !CLASSPATH!

java -Djava.library.path=lib com.etp.base.EAS
pause
```

[image]

Comment: The usage of `CLASSPATH` is deprecated. You should rather use `-cp` instead. But I can't see any error in that image. Your application seems to start

Comment: right,my Application Starts properly but the changes are done in Extension jar named as ETPEASV55_Ext.jar actually it doesn't load that jar so changes doesn't come in effect

Comment: Then you need to show us your Java code. That's impossible to answer otherwise. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: actually when I run this Same code through Eclipse it runs properly and works very fine

Comment: I have just a minimum understanding of this so I gotta ask: Do you have to use the classpath anywhere? Currently with setlocal the variable is just for the run of the batch-file or am I wrong? And you do not seem to use ClassPath at all, when calling your jar-file. Again: I have just a minimum/no understanding of creating / starting jars from cmd-line, so do not blame me for anything confusing ;)

Comment: if You see in the Image above you will notice that it is not able to load ClassPath for Resouces\plugjar